# Ensemble Forecast Distributions

Tags: time-series, probability, distributions, forecasting

Say multiple forecast methods each generate full forecast distributions. When using point forecasts one may average the point forecasts to get a ensemble forecast. What is the safest way to ensemble forecast distributions from various methods.

Comment: "from various methods" I'm afraid this is too broad a topic. Could you add more details about your setup and the aims of this analysis?

Comment: Generally, you want to integrate out the model index. How you do that depends on what form the individual distributions from each model take (e.g. in closed form, or as a sample, etc). I'm not sure what you mean by "safest".

Comment: I would have a holdout sample then do n-step ahead predictions and use those predictions as your input matrix to a linear regression with the target being your actual.  If you have more time-series than one then you can get fancier with this setup and use lightgbm/xgboost and give it some time series features as well such as acf coefficients and so on.  For a fancier solution to ensembling methods you should check out the second place winner from the M4 Competition, the team with Hyndman on it.

Comment: https://robjhyndman.com/seminars/nyrc2020/

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "full forecast distributions" or "ensemble forecast distribution'. If you mean use multiple methods to predict the future and then combining them then many recommend that. It has worked well for us.

Comment: I will add more information. Say you have 10 different methods each generating 5000 mcmc samples of expected future values. How should one average the top performing of the 10 methods. Can I just calculate the average of each order statistic? So say that of the 10 methods I decided I wanted to ensemble the top 3. Would I calculate that average of the min value for all three samples then the average of the second to the min value all the way to the average of the 5000th value?